# Specific Tor Bridges to Use USA Exit Relay Only

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, exit-relays, network-configuration

```
I am trying to configure Tor bridges that will use only USA exit Relays. 
Is this possible? I notice there are not that many *USA* exit relays, If there
are no available exit relays in the *US*, is TOR smart enough to fail over to
the next available exit relays or must that be included in the `.torcc`as well
?
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, but not the Bridges you need to configure. Bridges are "entry points"/"safe gates" to enter the Tor network. You need to select *an exit nodes/exits*, and that's how it's done in `torrc` config:

> ```
> StrictNodes 1
> ExitNodes {us}
> ```